# Intellij and JavaFX Exception

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

I am currently having an error thrown when attempting to start my program. The following error is this:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
at main.MainProgram.start(MainProgram.java:14)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
... 1 more
```

The code in my MainProgram.java file is the following:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainProgram extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resource/MainScreen.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 500));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And here is a photo of my directory layout:

[image: Photo of IntelliJ Project layout]

All JavaFX libraries have been installed correctly and VM options added. If anyone is able to help me sort this out, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the FXML file is not getting deployed to the build folder. Read the “troubleshooting” section of the linked question.

Comment: If you are using intellij, I highly recommend creating a new project following the Intellij [Create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) guide.  It is really simple, will create a project which just works for development, uses modern build tools, and is correctly laid out for both your project code, test code, and resources.  After you have created a new project, copy the code and resources from your original project into the new project and try it.  Note that when you need to bundle for deployment that is more complicated.